# Get changes on button tapped using Combine and SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, swiftui, combine

Trying to change `isValid` after the user have chose from the `Menu` the right position.

It seems to work if I first choose a position and then typing the email and name at the textfields but not the other side.

I want to enable the `Button` when he chose position and fulfilled the other textfields.

```
class EmployeeModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var employee: Employee
    @Published var isValid = false
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(employee: Employee = Employee(uid: "", affiliate: 0, employeeID: 1, email: "", name: "", shiftsConstIsApplied: false, position: nil, shiftConsts: nil, pushId: "")){
        
        self.employee = employee
        
        self.$employee
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            
            .map({!$0.name.isEmpty && !$0.email.isEmpty && $0.position != nil})
            .sink{ input in
                print(input)
                self.isValid = input
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

The view:

```
@State private var position: Positions?
@StateObject var employeeModel = EmployeeModel()

Menu(LocalizedStringKey(self.$position.wrappedValue?.rawValue ?? "Choose position")) {
                        ForEach(Positions.employeeTypes, id:\.self){ p in
                            Button(LocalizedStringKey(p)){
                                let positionSelected = Positions(rawValue: p)
                                self.position = positionSelected
                                self.employeeModel.employee.position = positionSelected
                            }
                        }
                    }

Button("Confirm"){
//do something
}
.disabled(!self.employeeModel.isValid)
```

Model Employee as ObservableObject:

```
    @Published var uid: String?
    @Published var email: String
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var affiliate: Int?
    @Published var employeeId: Int?
    @Published var shiftsConstIsApplied: Bool? = true
    @Published var position: Positions?
    @Published var shiftConsts: [ShiftConst]?
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your code try the following (not tested!)

```
init(employee: Employee = Employee(uid: "", affiliate: 0, employeeID: 1, email: "", name: "", shiftsConstIsApplied: false, position: nil, shiftConsts: nil, pushId: "")){
    
    self.employee = employee
    
    self.employee.objectWillChange               // << here !!
        .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
```

, you don't change employee itself (because it is reference type), but just its internal property, so you need to subscribe to its internal publisher.

Comment: I want to change the `isValid` from the internal properties from `self.employee`.
After the user entering its name and email, he needs to choose position, currently, when the user chose position `isValid` still = false. But, if I type email or name again (even just adding one char) than it works.
I want it to work after he chose position right away.